# <center> tag deprecated - No perfect replace

Tags: css, html, center

I'm running a simple website with basic HTML5 and CSS. (No CMS or anything, just old-school webdesign like 20 years ago)

To make things pretty (and optimized for mobile devices) i often use the `<center>` tag to... well... make things centered.

Now I'm often reading that the  tag is about to be abandoned. It still works (At least for Chrome and Firefox) but god knows how long it will still work.

Many forums and coding portals like W3Schools already posted an alternate solution using style variables or CSS.

New solution: `<div style="text-align:center">Random center text... Bla bla, Boohoo...</div>`

Unfortunately, it doesn't work for my website...

Neither the method inline Style (`<div style="text-align:center">`) works nor does the CSS method works (`<style>#coolcenterdude{text-align:center}</style><div id="coolcenterdude">`) Even doing this with external CSS documents doesn't work. It's just like the object that i'm trying to center is ignoring the text-align parameter.

Any help out there?

`<center>` still works fine, but i don't want my website get screwed when the tag is finally out of support.

Comment: If you are trying to center a table or a block with an explicit width, use `margin: 0 auto`.

Comment: Could you provide the code where you are using it? In my experience `text-align: center` works fine, just remember it centers the text in relation to the div, not the page.

Comment: I'm not using any tables. 99% of my website consists from div's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from what I understand you are looking for a way to center the site, so you need to use `margin:auto` with a `(max)-width`

Something like this:

```css
body {
  /* reset default body margins */
  margin: 0
}
#wrap {
  /* choose the value that fits you better - you can use another unit besides px */
  max-width: 300px;
  /* just for demo */
  height: 100vh;
  background: green;
  /* top-bottom :0 // left-right: auto */
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap"></div>
```

Comment: Yeah. That helped. Now the div's are centered. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if its a div you are trying to center, give margin: 0 auto, to that div element. text-align: center is for text content only.

You could try display flex if you dont have old browsers to support, or can use fallbacks and start using it.

Comment: The margin: 0 auto way helped. Thank you very much. Now i can delete all centers.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a global custom class to your css, say `centerElement` and add it to any element you want to center.

CSS:

```
.centerElement {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Now instead of this:

```
<center>
    <p>Some Random Text</p>
</center>
```

Do this:

```
<div class="centerElement">
    <p>Some Random Text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, i forgot to say that i tried both methods. ID's and Classes. Both don't work.

Comment: Please replicate an example in jsFiddle so I can provide a more accurate solution to your problem. Cheers

Comment: Nevermind. I already got the solution. "margin: 0 auto" helped me. But i appreciate your efforts to help me.